# What is the mutual intelligibility between the Standard German and Hessisch?

Tags: germanic-languages, german

If a native Standard German speaker from Leipzig listens to Hessisch spoken by an elderly person from Lich(a small town in Hessen), will he/she understand it?

Comment: That's an odd example because Leipzig's Upper Saxon is in the same Central dialect group.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_German as Hessian.  It's normal that a person from Leipzig would have at least a passive understanding of the local dialect, even across the major groups, knowing a dialect helps even with learning other faraway dialects, because they share features or at least differences from the standard language, i.e. dialect speakers know what the variables are (if they also know the standard language).

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Okay, but I've heard that the East Central German and the West Central German are mutually unintelligible.

Comment: Änd aj äm sagdschesting dät ju nid ta kwalifaj "intellidschibiliti" given dä kontekscht.  In praktis most dajalekts ar hard tu anderständ if ui hiir ä rändm sentenz widaut privias exposchur.  In praktis ui du hav privias exposchur änd sentencs ar not rändm änd so ui start tu akkaunt for dä pekjuliäritis äfter ä fju sentencs.

Comment: Well, there are many methods to determine a mutual intelligibility between two speeches, but I assume this might be the best method. Read 'Materials' and 'Methods' section of this paper : http://ling.hawaii.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019.Revising-the-Language-Map-ofKorea.pdf

Comment: The researchers of this paper showed a soundless video to speakers of Jeju and recorded their explanations on the video, arranged these recordings into a Jeju language script of the story, and then recorded them into an audio file. And they prepared questions about the script. Then, they played this to the Korean participants from the other regions, and showed them the questions, played pieces of them again while they were answering, and checked how many questions did they answered correctly to determine the mutual intelligibility between Jeju and Korean.